# Intellitrace fails when debugging Cannot debug some of the code in process w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellitrace

I've recently upgraded from VS2015 Professional Update 2 to VS2015 Enterprise Update 2.  The process was rather buggy.

First I attempted to upgrade directly from Pro Update 2 to Ent Update 1, as that was the media I had.  This provided all sorts of install errors.
C++ redistro install failed (version wrong), 
Connected Services (package failed)
Azure Connected Services (package failed)

Eventually I completely uninstalled Pro & C++ redistros (x86 & 64), rebooted and installed a fresh copy of Enterprise.  Installation went better as C++ didn't fail.  However, it left me in the same boat, with this error every time I start the debugger.

[image: IntelliTrace code failed.]

I've tried everything I can find:
- Unchecking "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"
- Many uninstalls and re-installs.

If I knew how to "disable debugging the failed type(s)"  I would.

The only successful solution I've seen so far was: 
"I solved it!  Reinstall windows and VS!"

Answer (score 1):

I've recently upgraded from VS2015 Enterprise Update 3. 
I encountered this warning. 
I solved it. Repair VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem with IntelliTrace
To quick solve it you can go to VS Options -> IntelliTrace and switch it off or check all.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when I updated ASP.NET Core NuGet dependency **Microsoft.AspNetCore.All** to **2.1.2** but corresponding SDK (2.1.302) has not been installed yet

Answer (score 0):

As for the most problems, restarting my PC solved the problem.