# Visual studio 2017 IntelliTrace code failed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, intellitrace

I created a C# Console App and tried to debug.
When Debug button is clicked then a popup appears
in Visual Studio 2017:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Cannot debug some of the code in process WpfApp.exe [1716]. See below for status.

    IntelliTrace code failed (0x80040154).
    Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0) code succeeded.

Click OK to continue debugging the remaining code.
To disable debugging the failed type(s) of code in the future,
change the corresponding setting in the project properties dialog.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It is the universal "class not registered" error code.  Makes it good idea to spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.  Just like [this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465156/17034).

Comment: Tried Repair But Not Resolved

Comment: @S. M. AMRAN, Sorry for that we couldn't repro this issue, whether all console projects have the same issue? How did you debug your app? Do you just add a breakpoint and debug your app directly or using the Attach to process window? If you disable the IntelliTrace under TOOLS->Option->IntelliTrace, how about the result? If possible, please share us the steps about how we could repro this issue. Or debug your app using F11 and enable Exception settings Windows, maybe you could find more useful information in your side.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I just added a break-point and hit debug button. This seems ok in previous versions of VS. I installed all of the packages in visual studio installer list. And updated to the 15.2 version of VS.

Comment: @S. M. AMRAN, I also installed the latest version, but no this issue. If possible, I suggest you re-install your VS, view the result. Not very sure that whether it will impacts the Environment if you install all packages in your side, but if possible, just install the main packages you will use, and then view the result. At least, we could narrow down this issue.

Comment: I Tried to Install on my Home PC By offline ISO of Full VS2017ENT made in my office. Some Packages might missing as I every time reinstall Visual Studio Installation completes with some Incomplete Package Installation Log. This might be possible reason.

Comment: @S. M. AMRAN, If it has the setup issue, I agree with you, it would be the possible reason which impact your development of projects. If possible, you could collect the setup logs and upload it to one drive, and then share the link here, I will help you analyze the setup log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks Jack a lot Replying this Thread with patience. Actually I setup
>   windows again :P

By the way, Is it possible to Make Visual Studio Installed Files Portable from Installed machine to another machine by just copying Installed Folder & Files. I am getting fan of Portable Installer. I make Portable every necessary IDE SDK Tools. Here is a short list. All is working fine just copying and extracting them. No Installation Hassel :P

```
Directory: C:\Data\Softs
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        6/13/2017  11:02 AM                Installer
d-----        6/14/2017   9:09 PM                Qt
d-----        6/13/2017  11:00 AM                SQLite
d-----        6/13/2017   9:07 AM                SQLyog 12.0.9-0 Ultimate for WXP+
------        6/14/2017   4:22 PM     3893336656 Android.7z
------        6/13/2017   3:03 PM         376880 dbdemo.7z
------        6/13/2017   3:23 PM       48180910 ffmpeg.zip
------        6/13/2017   3:56 PM       65809495 Git.7z
------        6/14/2017   1:54 PM       73331577 gradle-3.5-bin.zip
------        6/13/2017   2:59 PM      512640952 IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2.7z
------        6/13/2017   2:59 PM      245881993 JDK_1.8_131.7z
------        6/13/2017   3:02 PM      331427935 mysql-5.7.18-winx64.zip
------        6/13/2017   3:03 PM        4297296 mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.zip
------        6/13/2017   4:10 PM      293234040 NetBeans 8.2.7z
------        6/13/2017   3:56 PM        7771113 nodejs.7z
------        6/13/2017   3:25 PM       15914968 php.7z
------        6/13/2017   3:39 PM      209062685 PhpStorm 2017.1.4.7z
------        6/14/2017   1:03 PM      212330463 PyCharm 2017.1.3.7z
------        6/14/2017  11:24 AM       42243260 Python36.7z
------        6/13/2017   4:57 PM      867480324 Qt5.8.0.7z
------        6/13/2017   2:59 PM        7343878 SQLyog 12.0.9-0 Ultimate for WXP+.7z
------        6/14/2017   1:03 PM      195497091 WebStorm 2017.1.4.7z
------        6/13/2017   3:40 PM        7260701 WinSCP.7z
```

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer:)